# Swift: how to check stored property before creating an instance

Tags: ios, swift

for instance I have a class `Employee` with a list of stored properties. One of them is `birthdayDate` and second one is `startWorkDate`. Before init I want to add condition where want to check if `startWorkDate` greater than `birthdayDate`. And if so - create instance of the class, else throw fatalError.

`Date` already conformed to Equatable protocol. But can't get where exactly I need to implement this condition. Thanks.

```
class Employee {
    var name : String
    ...
    var birthdayDate : Date
    var startWorkDate : Date        
}
```

Comment: try fail-able init

Comment: Failable initializers: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Employee {
    var birthdayDate : Date
    var startWorkDate : Date

    init?(birthdayDate: Date, startWorkDate: Date) {
        guard startWorkDate > birthdayDate else { return nil }

        self.birthdayDate = birthdayDate
        self.startWorkDate = startWorkDate
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, ok. so easy:)